# Data Grid view not accepting passed parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, textbox

All,  I have a datagridview with a SQL field named "WorkDate." I'm passing in a parameter VIA a textbox and button click. The only records that should display are the ones for the date entered. I can see where the date parameter is being passed, but the datagrid is not reflecting the correct records for the specific date. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is where I'm passing the parameter:

```
    Protected Sub btnSubmit0_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit0.Click

    Response.Redirect("~/datagridreview.aspx?WorkDate=" + TextBox3.Text.Trim())
End Sub
```

End Class

Here you can see that the parameter is being passed, but not reflected in the Data Grid. [Data Grid Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avopO.png)

Comment: how you are accepting value in datagridview.aspx

Comment: have you checked if the date being sent has the correct format?

Comment: Hi, @AnoopLL thanks so much for your response. I'm accepting it VIA a select parameter statement. Like this:  <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="WorkDate" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <SelectParameters/>

Comment: string workDate = Request.QueryString["WorkDate"]; try this in datagridview.aspx

Comment: @JTroy change ControlParameter to QueryStringParameter

Comment: @S.Dav thanks for the response, I have checked and the date is being sent in the correct format.

Comment: @AnoopLL I couldn't get that change to work, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @BrianMains I'm trying your suggestion now. Thank you for the response.

Comment: All, I haven't been able to get any of the above solutions to work. Do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: Can we see your search? When you hit submit where is it calling the gridview to search?

Comment: Hi @KratosMafia thanks for the response. I'm calling the search on a button click.  Protected Sub btnSubmit0_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit0.Click

    Response.Redirect("~/datagridreview.aspx?WorkDate=" + TextBox3.Text.Trim())
End Sub

Comment: Any one have any more thoughts?  Any help would certainly be appreciated...

Comment: please post code of datagridview.aspx page also